# Finding missing C code, given assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

The code is

```
int f(int x, int y, int z) {
  if (/* missing code here */)
    return z;
  else
    return -z;
}
```

And the assembly is

```
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl 12(%ebp), %eax
    jge .L2
    movl 16(%ebp), %eax
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    movl 16(%ebp), %eax
    negl %eax
.L3:
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

And the question asks for me to find what the missing test expression must be to yield the assembly code given. Okay, easy enough. There is an obvious comparison going on between `x` and `y`. The `jge` operator is going to preform the jump into the body of the loop if `12(%ebp) > %eax`.

The possible choices are

`x<=y`
`x>=y`
`x>y`
`x<y`

My answer was `x<=y`, since `12(%ebp)` is a reference to `y`, and it is the destination. But this answer was wrong, and I do not see how. Any hints? Thank you so much.

Comment: Does jge not mean : jump greater or equal? `>=`

Comment: You could decompile/disassemble but honestly there isn't much there, so you could probably try to figure out what happens yourself. I think it's doing x - y (`8(%ebp)` and `12(%ebp)` are the first two function arguments off of the stack) and then jumping if it's greater than zero. Which, to me, would imply that x is greater than y.

Comment: Using intel syntax and pseudo code, the compare is equivalent to `cmp x, y`. From here, we get to the `return -z` branch if x >= y. Since we want to know what the tested condition is, we simply reverse this test, thus giving us the test that must result in true for the desired branch. It soon becomes clear that the actual tested condition was x < y (i.e not x>=y)

Comment: The answer given by both of you seems simple enough. It was just my understanding that jge jumps if the _first_ value given to the `cmp` call is greater than the second. Is that wrong?

Comment: @enhzflep That makes complete sense, I just stopped a step too early. Thank you! If you write this as an answer I will mark as sovled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the annotated x86 assembly:

`pushl %ebp ; save the old stack
 movl %esp, %ebp ; set up your local, new stack
 movl 8(%ebp), %eax ; take the first function argument and store it into eax
 cmpl 12(%ebp), %eax ; compare the 2nd function arg with the 1st (in eax)`

After this, there's a `jge` which means, essentially, "jump if greater than or equal", which you can do after the `cmp` instruction.

This means that it jumps if the first argument is greater than the second argument, and thus, `x >= y`.

However, this jump (to L2) will actually negate z, and then return z. **What you actually want is the jump to L3, which would happen if x < y, which should be the end result.**

Comment: I wonder why parameters are passed on the stack instead of registers, according to the calling convention.

Comment: @black, Assuming Linux, the code in the question appears to be 32-bit so parameters are generally passed on the stack (32-Bit i386 ABI) unlike the System V 64-bit ABI where parameters that fit can be passed in registers (and if need be on the stack)

Answer (score 2):

You can ask GCC, what it will do. Create a source with several functions:

**test.c**

```
int f1 (int x, int y, int z) {
  if (x < y)
    return z;
  else
    return -z;
}

int f2 (int x, int y, int z) {
  if (x > y)
    return z;
  else
    return -z;
}

int main ( void )
{
    return 0;
}
```

`f1` performs (x < y), `f2` performs (x > y). Now build it:

```
gcc test.c -m32 -Wa,-ahln -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables
```

You see the assembly of `test.c`. Look for `f1:` and `f2:`, which are the entry points of the functions. Which one matches your snippet? You will see, that `f1` matches, whereas `f2` handles with `jle`.